# Invalid bitcode signature while building in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build a very old iOS Cordova App.

It builds successfully for Simulators but, when I try to build for any real hardware, it shows error:

> Ld
>   /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MIND_MIS.app/MIND_MIS
>   normal armv7s
>       cd "/Users/atif/Desktop/Atif/Projects/MIS/MIND_MIS Ver 02.00.0002 Final"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MIND_MIS.build/Debug-iphoneos/MIND_MIS.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MIND_MIS.LinkFileList
>   -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MIND_MIS.build/Debug-iphoneos/MIND_MIS.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MIND_MIS_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation
>   -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -ObjC -framework MessageUI -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework OpenAL -framework
>   AssetsLibrary
>   /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork
>   -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework
>   CoreMedia -framework CoreLocation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MIND_MIS.build/Debug-iphoneos/MIND_MIS.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MIND_MIS_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/atif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MIND_MIS-cccdiojxhigimnewheisujbzuhyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MIND_MIS.app/MIND_MIS
>
> error: Invalid bitcode signature clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I even tried using Xcode 7, 8 and also 9 but, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- Clear derived data and then reopen Xcode.
- Select proper sign in / certificate, or try to re-add account in Xcode.
- Make sure if your pods supported bitcode if not then you need to set bitcode to NO (Go to Project Build setting search for bitcode & set it to NO.

  ---

  **Or** trying this may help you:
  [image]

  ---

  **OR**
- Open Podfile
- Uncomment this line ~> platform :ios, 'x.0'
- From the command line run the following command where Podfile resides
- pod update
- In the xcode select Product > clean and then Product > Build

Comment: Its now showing:
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EmailComposer in EmailComposer.o

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?

Comment: I am not using cocoa pods

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error before..

Try this solution:

**Go to Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only**

```
Make changes on the selected target

a) Set it as 'YES' if you're building/pushing the app directly to a device

b) Set it as 'NO' if you're trying to build the app as IPA
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to project > targets > general > deployment info. Make sure your deployment target is same as your hardware's ios version